# How to build WDDM driver vidpn

Tags: windows, driver

I am writing WDDM filter driver for creating virtual displays.

I support the virtual child device and video source associated paths in the DxgkDdiIsSupportedVidPn function, such as Paths(source->target):(0 <-> 0), (1 <-> 4),

DxgkDdiEnumVidPnCofuncModality function specifies the target ID = 4, other target IDs are omitted, in Here I add source mode and target mode to this ID=4 path.

I can see multiple monitors in Desktop Properties → Resolution, but I can't modify the resolution of the monitor and extend the desktop, this monitor Can't save display settings error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main graphics adapter must not see the additional monitor, but dxgkrnl.sys must see it and all the existing monitors of the main graphics adapter, too.

Comment: You can mail it to me:dailongjian2008@126.com